# How to make a search function that search an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search

I have an array of objects like this how do i search in this array of objects after certain string pattern?

If I enter 'B' result should be 'bent' and 'benny

If I enter 'benn' result should be 'benny'

HTML

```
<form>
    <input id="getCoins" type="text" name="getCoins" placeholder="">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var input = document.getElementById("getCoins");
var arr = [0:{name: 'bent', town: 'kansas'}1:{ name:'benny', town:'vegas'}]
input .addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    console.log(filterIt(arr, input.value));
}
```

This is what I tried from another post but I could not get it to work?

```
function filterIt(arr, searchKey) {
    return arr.filter(function (obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
            return obj[key].includes(searchKey);
        })
    });
}
```

NOTE: I only want to search the name, not town

Comment: *"I could not get it to work"* - it doesn't work at all? It works, but incorrectly?

Comment: This is wrong: `var arr = [0:{name: 'bent', town: 'kansas'}1:{ name:'benny', town:'vegas'}]`. Sould be: `var arr = [
        {name: 'bent', town: 'kansas'},
        {name:'benny', town:'vegas'}
      ];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first define a function that determines the filter condition given a *single item*. This function should return a boolean if the item should be *included*.

```
function match(inputValue, item) { /* .... */ }
```

Then you can use this function in the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function like so:

```
var matchingValues = arr.filter(match.bind(null, input.value));
```

Since the `match()` function takes two arguments, but `filter()` only passes its callback one item at a time, we [partially apply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) the match function using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and `input.value` to turn the `match()` function into a function 
that will only expect the item.

This is the same as doing:

```
var matchingValues = arr.filter(function (item) { 
  return match(input.value, item); 
});
```

I find that the code looks much tidier and easier to understand if you use partial application.

Oh, and one of the commenters pointed out that the OP only wants the `name` part. In that case, simply chain a `.map()` call to extract the name:

```
var matchingNames = arr
  .filter(function (item) { 
    return match(input.value, item); 
  })
  .map(function (item) {
    return item.name;
  });
```

EDIT: You should also fix the array:

```
var arr = [{name: 'bent', town: 'kansas'}, { name:'benny', town:'vegas'}]
```

I suggest investing some time in setting up [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) and integrating that into your editor, so your code looks presentable and is at least free of syntax errors.

Comment: It is because i am retrieving a json object which i push into an array like this

                    `var coins = [];
                    for (var l in jsonObj) {
                        coins.push(jsonObj[l]);
                    }`

Comment: Still, your code snippet would produce a syntax error in real life.

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterIt(arr, searchKey) {
    return arr.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.name.search(searchKey) != -1;
    });
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to search the `name` only, he wants to search all properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` to iterate over the array and then `for..in` to iterate over each object. Declare an array at the top of the function, then push any matches into an the array and return that.

```
function findMatches(arr, searchString){
  const matches = [];

  arr.forEach((obj) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
      if (obj[key].includes(searchString)){
        matches.push(obj[key]);
      }
    }
  });

  return matches;
}

const arr = [
  {name: 'bent', town: 'kansas'},
  {name:'benny', town:'vegas'}
];

console.log(findMatches(arr, "b"));
// => ["bent", "benny"]

console.log(findMatches(arr, "benn"));
// => ["benny"]
```

Comment: Instead of using `forEach()` and an accumulator array, you can use `filter()` and do it all in one go.You can use this expression to test if an `obj` is a match: `Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) { return obj[key].toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase()) })`

Comment: You sure? That just returns two empty arrays for me.

Comment: Ah right, I was missing a `return`. Thanks. Two points though: this returns the whole object and I understood the OP to be searching for specific strings. Also, when I revisit this code in 6 months or whatever, with my more verbose version, I will know immediately what I was doing, whereas with your more concise version, I'll have to think my way back into that function to remember what it was doing. Thanks for providing it though. That is appreciated :)

Comment: Whether you return the whole object or just a string is trivial to modify. As for whether you will be able to know what the code does depends on whether you remain at your current JS fluency when the time comes. Pretty sure this pattern becomes a no-brainer once you master filter, map, etc.

Comment: Interesting. How would you modify it to return the matched strings? This got me stuck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156731/discussion-between-hayavuk-and-jack-zelig).

Answer (score 0):

The more optimized solution would be to extract the initial ***name/town*** words beforehand. Then, on each `keyup` event - search just within that string.

The solution with `RegExp` object and `String.match()` function:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("getCoins"),
    arr = [{name: 'bent', town: 'kansas'},{ name:'benny', town:'vegas'}],
    item_str = arr.map((o) => Object.values(o).join(' ')).join(' ');

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    var pat = new RegExp('\\w*'+e.target.value+'\\w*', 'gi');
    console.log(item_str.match(pat));
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="getCoins" type="text" name="getCoins" placeholder="">
</form>
```